# Java Wicket 7 can't use addKey(String key) method

Tags: java, deprecated, wicket-7

in wicket 7 `addKeyMessage(String key)` method is deprecated from IValidationError interface. What I can use instead of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried checking javadoc? https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/validation/ValidationError.html#addMessageKey(java.lang.String)

> Deprecated. use addKey(String)

It looks like it was just renamed.